# Why am I constantly asked to prove I am human?

Tags: discussion

I understand the need to filter out bots, but this site seems to ask every 3rd or 4th question. I have a decent usage record, can't it just assume, after a certain number of times and from certain IP's that I am human?

Comment: In testament to this, it just asked me to confirm again.

Comment: *@Mild Fuzz* - Maybe it's because the system can tell you don't have a photo for an avatar?  Just sayin... ;-)

Comment: You don't want to see my face, Mike. Your eyes couldn't take it.